# Why 'Application.Calculation=[value]' statement in Excel VBA erases Clipboard Memory?

Tags: excel, clipboard, copy-paste, worksheet-function, vba

**PROBLEM DEFINITION**: In the following Excel VBA sample code snippet (see Listing 1), which is intended just to Copy-Paste the content of Cell "A1" to cell 'A2", the line:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

seemingly erases Clipboard Memory, causing a Run-time error. Moreover, any of the following similar statements will produce the same effect:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

*Listing 1.*

```
'demo Sub demonstrating Clipboard Memory flash by the statement
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Sub CopyPaste()
    'select cell with some test value
    Range("A1").Select

    'selected value is copied to Clipboard memory
    Selection.Copy

    'This statement seemingly erases Clipboard memory
    'causing Run-Time Error 1004
    'if this line is commented-off, the procedure will run normally
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' test if clipboard is empty ---------------------
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    If Err Then MsgBox "Error num: " & Err.Number & "|Clipboard is Empty": Err.Clear
    '-------------------------------------------------

    'target cell to copy value from Clipboard
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

If you comment-off the aforementioned statement, procedure will run flawless.

**QUESTION: Is it true that Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual statement flashes Clipboard Memory, and if so, why?**

Any reference to a Microsoft Excel documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is it true?* Apparently so. I had never noticed; but I just tested it and that's what it does. So yes, it's true.

*Why?* Well, who knows. We'd have to ask the Microsoft developers what was going through their heads, or whether this was at all intended. But I don't see how knowing the "why" would be of any practical use.

The important thing is a proper workaround: move `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` to the top of your code, or at least before the `Copy` statement.

Even better, avoid using the clipboard entirely, and certainly avoid using the `Select`-`Selection` notation:

```
Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Range("A2")
```

or to copy the value only:

```
Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Value
```

or, for full control:

```
Dim temp as variant
temp = Range("A1").Value
'manipulate temp here if you so wish
Range("A2").Value = temp
```